# ASP.NET: How to change DynamicControl Mode programatically

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, controls, mode

I would like to change DynamicControl mode programatically in ASP.NET.
I have already tried two methods but I failed both times.
First i tried do perform it in code behind. Mode of DynamicControls is set to "Edit". On page load I iterated over controles and tried to change mode like this

```
((DynamicControl)c).Mode = DataBoundControlMode.ReadOnly;
```

This did not produce any results.

In second method I used inline expressions in aspx page.

```
Mode= "<%#getDynamicControlMode(MPFormView) %>"
```

and the function used in code behind is

```
public DataBoundControlMode getDynamicControlMode(FormView fv)
    {
        if (fv.CurrentMode == FormViewMode.ReadOnly)
            return DataBoundControlMode.ReadOnly;
        else if (fv.CurrentMode == FormViewMode.Edit)
            return DataBoundControlMode.Edit;
        else
            return DataBoundControlMode.Insert;
    }
```

This method failed also, controls stayed in ReadOnly Mode regardless of FormViewMode.
I want to do this programaticall because I want to use only one template in FormView.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found out that i need to dig into DynamicControl to get underlaying controls.
So i solved my problem using following code:

```
                  foreach (Control ct in cont.Controls)//cont is the DynamicControl
                       {
                           foreach (Control ci in ct.Controls)
                           {
                               if (ci is CheckBox)
                                   ((CheckBox)ci).Enabled = enable;
                               if (ci is TextBox)
                                   ((TextBox)ci).Enabled = enable;
                           }
                       }
```

This way i have disabled controls but it suits me as well.